# JuJu / Landscape OpenStack Install - No network listing for Open vSwitch

Tags: networking, juju, maas, openstack, landscape

My set up has 8 physical machines, and 1 VM for MAAS.

My network is comprised of 3 subnets. 2 of them are untagged, and the third is tagged.

The first untagged network contains the 'public' IP for MAAS (to ssh into with).
The second untagged network is the MAAS private network containing IPs for the physical serverss.
The tagged network is what I assumed to be installing openstack onto via landscape.

My MAAS server has 2 NICs and network.config is configured for the tagged network on the 2nd NIC.

The physical servers also have 2 NICs.
1 server is planned for landscape,
1 for juju,
6 for openstack

In MAAS I have 3 fabrics, one for each of my networks. The 6 openstack nodes have their NICs configured within MAAS to connect to the 'openstack' fabric with the IP address left at 'unconfigured', and to connect to the MAAS private network.

I have successfully deployed an openstack bundle via juju deploy (NOT VIA THE JUJU WEB GUI, IT ALWAYS FAILS). But, this deployment is always on the private maas subnet, not my tagged openstack subnet.

**My main issue** is that when I deploy a landscape juju charm bundle, and then within the web app start to configure an openstack deployment, open vswitch does not contain any networks to select from the "public network" dropdown menu... The dropdown menu is completely blank...

If you need any additional information feel free to ask.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please see the following for the official word on the Openstack "Autopilot" offering in the Landscape tool:

https://insights.ubuntu.com/2014/11/06/putting-your-openstack-on-autopilot/

Specifically, Here is the text from Canonical:

> Thanks for your interest in Ubuntu OpenStack. Canonical has sunsetted
>   OpenStack Autopilot and replaced it with [conjure-up](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/try-openstack). We welcome you to
>   visit our [OpenStack product page](https://www.ubuntu.com/cloud/openstack) to find an Ubuntu OpenStack solution
>   that meets your needs.

Answer (score 0):

i had that issue and i found that in autopilot you need to have a "public" networks as unconfigured. Your "internal" network can be configured as auto assign of IP addresses. Hope this helps you.